# Working free text-editor for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, text-editor

Does anyone have a free text-editor that works well in Windows 7?  I'm currently useing Programmer's Notpad 2, but it keeps crashing or having UI bug issues.

---

### LIST

- [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/)
- [NOTEPAD++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)
- [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [Zeus Lite](http://zeusedit.com/lite/)
- [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notepad++ is working fine for me with no problems.

Answer (score 5):

I like these on Windows systems.
As far as I know, they all work with Windows 7.

Hard to learn, but makes you more efficient in the long run:

- [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php)
- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Easy to learn, but still powerful editor:

- [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net)

Comment: +1 for hilarity: "refuse to put any effort into your own productivity"

Answer (score 4):

[Zeus Lite](http://zeusedit.com/lite/)

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++

I really like Sublime Edit and it works well, but (not very often) shows an alert "Please purchase" (not very annoying. really). You should try!
It can even do editing with many cursors, it has cool snippet engine, it has very useful for projects combination Ctrl+P, etc

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) on Windows 7 and they both work fine.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net) rulz

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), which works fine on Windows 7.

Beware, though: The user interface elements and keyboard shortcuts are completely different from everything you are used to from Windows (which isn't surprising, since its origins are not in the Windows world). If that's OK for you, you will be rewarded with one of the most powerful text editors in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever gets your code out and makes you feel comfortable in the process! At the end of the day, it's all preference! :^)

However, I have liked Sublime text for it's nice GUI, similar to TextMate on Mac (if that's where you're coming from). Long time Emacs user, got tired of having to implement every feature that comes with a lot of text editors today...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna have to throw my vote out there for [Vim](http://www.vim.org). It's got a steep learning curve, but once you learn it you wonder how you ever coded without it before.

There's something immensely re-assuring about the whole modal way of doing things. It kind of enforces the concept that your code is a structure to be engineered and architected correctly, not a collection of letters that will blow away at the first sneeze.

Wow, that metaphor was a stretch, wasn't it.